# What is the limit to the number of simultaneous connections in Bonjour?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, scalability, bonjour

I'm developing an iPhone app that allows users to connect to other iPhones using the Bonjour protocol. One of the users hosts a server and publishes his bonjour service and the other client users discover his service and connect to it to exchange data. Does anyone know if Bonjour itself imposes a limit on the number of concurrent connections connected to a server and if so, what that limit might be? Is Bonjour a suitable choice if you're looking to support 20+ iPhones connected to an iPhone hosting a server-like application? Or is Bonjour only suitable for less than 5 simultaneous connections? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonjour itself does not impose this kind of limit.

It's purpose is to make the service (server for example) discoverable.

So yes, Bonjour would be appropriate choice for your needs.

All the limits are (will be) imposed from your implementation of the server.

Comment: Yay, I was hoping for an answer like this! Thanks!